# Sencha Touch - Dynamic creation of form fields using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm new to Sencha Touch, and I need to create a form where you can pick from a category from a select box, and after picking it, the form fields coresponding to this category should be generated and displayed.
The relation between category and fields lays in a MSSQL db.
Until now I've managed to load the combobox with categories from my db, but now i'm not sure how to proceed.
Can you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creating the dynamic UI is very simple, we have to use the constructor rather using lazy initialization (xtype). These are the few steps.

1.Get the complete information of categories and related other field information in the form of json.

{
    categories: "AA",
        values : [{
        }]
}, {
    categories: "AA",
        values : [{
        }]
}

2.Filter the values, or fields dynamically and create rest of the UI on value change from the categories field. This is efficient if you have not more number of controls to be rendered on screen on change of categories values.

Start coding, by making the web services ready.